# Excel VBA Print External File

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have this code that I found while doing a google search. It seems to open the text file just fine, but I want to print the file. Can anyone see what is missing here and tell me why it is not printing?  Thanks

```
Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias _
   "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation _
   As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters _
   As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd _
   As Long) As Long

Declare Function apiFindWindow Lib "User32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
   (ByVal lpclassname As Any, ByVal lpCaption As Any) As Long

Global Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1

Sub ShellExecuteExample()
   Dim hwnd
   Dim StartDoc
   hwnd = apiFindWindow("OPUSAPP", "0")

   StartDoc = ShellExecute(hwnd, "print", "C:\Scripts\print.vba.test.txt", "", _
      "C:\", SW_SHOWNORMAL)
End Sub
```

Comment: Why would you like to print a text file from within Excel? Isn't it like going fishing with a aircraft carrier?

Comment: I have text files that contain specific information that is related to a task being performed in a Excel Userform.

Comment: I see. I'm guessing now... Excel knows how to print Workbooks and Spreadsheets. You should try to convert (internally within Excel) the loaded text to something Excel knows how to handle. For instance, you could have a big collection of cells (say, 20 columns and 200 rows) merged into a single cell, and paste the contents of the file into that cell. Then, you can ask Excel to print the spreadsheet to contains that cell.